# asp.net ajax server side error handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am using Telerik ajax controls in VS2010 asp.net web project. 
I am only targetting IE v8 browser.

When I encounter server side code exception, I get an error dialog box "There was an error in the call back."

When I click okay, nothing happens at the server side and code stops executing.

**I exactly know where the error is.. I just want it to bubble up to Global.asax Application_Error.**

In this web application, there is no try catch exception handling any where. All the exception bubble up to Application_Error in global.asax.
In this specific case, how can I bubble up the exception to Global.asax?

The following post accurately describe what I am trying to achieve. Back in 2009 it was not possible.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/load-on-demand-and-exception-handling.aspx#2359140

Is it possible now?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: So if you let the error occur, do you currently have Application_Error defined in your Global.asax page to deal with it?

Comment: yes.. I have logging code etc. in Application_Error to capture error details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a part of an ajax request you don't necessarily get your error bubbled up to the global asax. your client script sends a request then you have an error in the server and that's sent back to the client, a failure or a generic failure message). Server side (given your ajax request reached the server side) . You can still trap your error, but that's about it. To make things more difficult, as your are using a third part control, you don't even know if the exception is really raised.
checklist

```
 url --> are you reaching the server
 sever -> does the control raise exceptions.
 error trapping -> consider implementing loggin
 request debugging -> you can use a tool like fiddler or firebug to emulate the request, debug in visual studio and track the error down.
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar kind of issues while using telerik controls, particularly working on ajax operations. I would suggest you to use fiddler or firebug to verify if links are correctly pointed and then check for any server side errors.

Note: I did realize for JQuery AJAX requests, 404 exception is getting caught in global error event. But however as I mentioned, in telerik ajax controls, I had faced this kind of issues but I have no idea it getting caught.